# Как подставить $i в название функции в цикле?

Tags: php

Нужно запустить много функций в цикле, у которых только цифры в названии отличаются

Существует функция:

```
func1_1() {
  //something code here
}
```

А надо сделать какое-то кол-во таких ф-ий: func1_2(), func1_3()....func2_1(), func2_2()...

В стремлении укоротить код пытаюсь сделать это с помощью цикла:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
    func'.($i+1).'_'.($j+1).'()' {//тут проблемы с синтаксисом, вот этот момент и интересует
      //something code here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "В стремлении укоротить код " --- в этом стремлении вы делаете какую-то дичь.

Comment: Какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить наплодив таких функций?

Comment: Понимаю, что, возможно, не по тому пути иду, но даже если в дальнейшем откажусь от этой идеи, в целях общего развития такие вещи надо знать. Пытаюсь решить проблему: API настроек (опций) в wordpress.

Comment: тут-то всё просто. надо уметь работать со строками `$function = "func{$i}_{$j}"; $function();` ......... а вот "решить проблему настроек API" ни о чём не говорит. Подробнее?

Comment: Ваш вариант я проверил хотя это несколько не то, что мне нужно - он выдает ошибку: syntax error, unexpected end of file in.  Мне нужен конечный вид такого плана:  `func{i}_{j}() {
  //something code here
}`

Comment: по поводу API (раз уж вам интересно): вот статья https://wp-kama.ru/id_3773/api-optsiy-nastroek.html/comment-page-1#comments-section     Пытаюсь создать дополнительные поля типа телефон, адрес и пр. (полей будет много)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве бреда к бреду:

```
$functionsHolder = [];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
        $functionsHolder["func{$i}_{$j}"] = function() use ($i, $j) {
            echo "Это функция {$i}_{$j}";
        };
    }
}



for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= 3; $j++) {
        $functionsHolder["func{$i}_{$j}"]();
        echo "\n";
    }
}
// Или так
// array_walk_recursive($functionsHolder, function($function) {
//    $function();
//    echo "\n";
//});

// Output:

Это функция 1_1
Это функция 1_2
Это функция 1_3
Это функция 2_1
Это функция 2_2
Это функция 2_3
Это функция 3_1
Это функция 3_2
Это функция 3_3
```

Comment: Не считаю свой вопрос бредовым и благодарю за ответ, очень интересно.